# what's the usage of inherit 'dict' with a class?

Tags: python

I saw one of my colleague write his code like:

```
class a(dict):
    # something
    pass
```

Is this a common skill?  What does it serve for?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21694054 eventhough its C#

Comment: Given that what you post isn't syntactically correct, it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @chepner, sorry for my mistake, already fixed.

Comment: Maybe this clears things up: `class MyDict(dict)`

Comment: @keyser, I don't think he want to make a MyDict class here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done when you want a class with the default behaviour of a dictionary (getting and setting keys), but the instances are going to be used in highlu specific circumstances, and you anticipate the need to provide custom methods or constructors specific to those.

For example, you may want have a dynamic `KeyStorage` that starts as a in-memory store, but later adapt the class to keep the data on disk.

You can also mangle the keys and values as needed - for storage of unicode data on a database with a specific encoding, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it makes sense. For example you could create a dict that allows case insensitive lookup:

```
class case_insensitive_dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(case_insensitive_dict, self).__getitem__(key.lower())

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return super(case_insensitive_dict, self).__setitem__(key.lower(), value)


d = case_insensitive_dict()
d["AbCd"] = 1
print d["abcd"]
```

(this might require additional error handling)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the built-in dict class can be useful to create dict "supersets" (e.g. "bunch" class where keys can be accessed object-style, as in javascript) without having to reimplement `MutableMapping`'s 5 methods by hand.

But if your colleague literally writes

```
class MyDict(dict):
    pass
```

without any customisation, I can only see evil uses for it, such as adding attributes to the dict:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a.foo = 3
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> b = MyDict()
>>> b.foo = 3
>>>
```

Comment: He wrote a lot of other codes. I think he is going to use self['key'] = value method